# Qt4, direct assignment of QPainterPath not working (unresolved external)

Tags: c++, qt, linker

I am trying to do this (directDrawingPainterPath is a class member of type QPainterPath):

```
directDrawingPainterPath = QPainterPath(point);
```

However, compiling the program in visual studio gets me the following error:

> 1>ScribbleWidget.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: class QPainterPath & _*cdecl
>   QPainterPath::operator=(class QPainterPath &&)"
>   (*_imp_??4QPainterPath@@QEAAAEAV0@$$QEAV0@@Z) referenced in function
>   "protected: virtual void __cdecl ScribbleWidget::mousePressEvent(class
>   QMouseEvent *)"
>   (?mousePressEvent@ScribbleWidget@@MEAAXPEAVQMouseEvent@@@Z)

When I rewrite it like this:

```
QPainterPath tmp(point);
directDrawingPainterPath = tmp;
```

Then it works. This also happens for other assignments:

This works:

```
QString tmp = att.value().toString();
name = tmp;
```

This doesn't:

```
name = att.value().toString();
```

Anyone knows what the problem could be?

**Update**

I just found the solution: The problem was that I tried to link against a QT that was compiled with VS2008, while I compiled the project with VS2010.

Using a QT that's also compiled with VS2010 makes everything work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution: The problem was that I tried to link against a QT that was compiled with VS2008, while I compiled the project with VS2010.

Using a QT that's also compiled with VS2010 makes everything work...

Answer (score 1):

looks like you are compilling in C++11 mode because of the error:
 QPainterPath::operator=(class QPainterPath &&)
this is an 'rvalue reference', wich Qt didn't implemented yet. It means that you are returning a Temporary Value from a method or function, and assigning that value to a variable.

When you store your value in a tmp variable ( QPainterPath tmp(point); rectDrawingPainterPath = tmp; ) you are using the normal operator= method, so it works.

try to disable the C++0x in Visual Studio, cant help with that, since I never used it. :)

Comment: Very good observation... however, the problem was somewhere else (see my update to the question). But thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Is the following in your project file for both release and debug builds ?

`LIBS +=  $$quote(PathtoQtLib/NameofQtLib.lib)`

where PathtoQtLib is something like C:\Qt\4.8.0\lib and NameofQtLib is QtGui4.lib .

If you aren't using a project file, do you have the libraries you are linking to configured correctly ?

Comment: The linking can't be the problem since it works when I rewrite the code a little bit, as stated... however, I found the solution now (see Update). Thanks for the help, anyway.